# How to stop MATLAB from opening a new window using Cygwin?

Tags: windows, matlab, cygwin

In the past, I have used MATLAB sparingly from Linux machines at work, and I far and away preferred using the '-nodesktop' option. On all Unix-like machines I've worked on this option allows me to control STDIN and STOUT with relative ease, but on Windows(using Cygwin) this option spawns a new window and control is returned to the calling shell!

Basically, I would like to know if there is any way that I can force MATLAB to behave as it would on a Unix-like machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can not.

A longer answer can be found on their [website](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/).

> -nodesktop behaves differently depending if you are on Windows vs
>   Linux or Mac. On Windows we provide a boring Command-Window only
>   interface that lacks the “bells and whistles” of the regular Command
>   Window or the full Desktop.

So you can use -nodesktop, but it pops up that annoying command line only window.

Comment: I've read this on their website, but nowhere do they state you cannot do what I have described.

Comment: Well good luck finding any magical options that do not exist.